# how to crawl all the pages of a website

Tags: web-crawler

I am working on a web crawler. I want to get all the links of pages and then crawl all that pages for this i m using below code

```
<?php
set_time_limit (0);
function crawl_robot($url, $depth = 5){
    $seen = array();
    if(($depth == 0) or (in_array($url, $seen))){
    return;
}
$seen[] = $url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if( $result ){
    $stripped_file = strip_tags($result, "<a>");
    preg_match_all("/<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+"."(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/", $stripped_file, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
    foreach($matches as $match){
        $href = $match[1];
            if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
                $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
                if (extension_loaded('http')) {
                    $href = http_build_url($href, array('path' => $path));
                } else {
                    $parts = parse_url($href);
                    $href = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
                    if (isset($parts['user']) && isset($parts['pass'])) {
                        $href .= $parts['user'] . ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@';
                    }
                    $href .= $parts['host'];
                    if (isset($parts['port'])) {
                        $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                    }
                    $href .= $path;
                }
            }
            crawl_robot($href, $depth - 1);
        }
    }
print_r(array_unique($seen));
}
crawl_robot("http://www.barringtonsports.com/", 3)
?>
```

it displays these errors

Notice: Undefined index: scheme in C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\test.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\test.php on line 69

Comment: from [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), if the url you are parsing does not contain a part (`scheme` or `host`) then the value will not be set.  i suspect that the links you are scraping from the page are relative links and thus don't have the two values you are missing.  can you `print_r($href)` to confirm or deny this?

Comment: you can use http://crawlmysite.in . Works good